# Seaborn catplot, float to int abscissa

Tags: seaborn

I would like to read  my seaborn chart more clearly. Basically, I have X values ranging from 0 to 11 but they are float values. When I plot my chart, it's impossible to read correctly the X values : the tick are in float and there are too many values. The "funny" thing is that my Y values are similar but they are correctly plotted with integer interval ranging from 0 to 11.

I tried this tips that I found on stackoverflow but it didn't work:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, _: int(x)))
```

This is my code for plotting.

```py
dataset = pd.read_csv("/workspace/Classification/for_classification.csv", delimiter=";")
sns.catplot(x="X1", y="X2", hue="LABEL", data=dataset);
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, _: int(x)))
```

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Catplot is a categorical plot, it hence creates one tick and ticklabel per unique data. I suspect that you want to use something other than a catplot.

Comment: Are you trying to bin your x data in a discrete number of categories? As you can see from the comments of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 's and me, you do not provide enough information to understand your problem. Please provide an example dataset, show the resulting graph and explain what you would like the desired ouput to be.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. An example of my dataset is the following (X1; X2) (0.75 ; 1.25) (1.75 ; 3.2) ... Basically, I created a very simple dataset with random points and for each of those points, if 1/2 x X1 - X2 > 0 then I have a third variable (LABEL) that take the value 1 and 0 otherwise. Everything works fine with the cat plot, I can plot my points correctly and give them a color depending on the Y value. But somehow, the X2 axis has value from 0 to 10 with a step of 1 (even when X2 takes float values). But X1 axis has value from 0 to 10 with a step of 0.01... Is it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `relplot` instead.

```
b.relplot(x="X1", y="X2", hue="LABEL", data=dataset)
```